# PowerShell file existence check returns false negative

Tags: powershell

Quite simply, I need to check if a file exists in the user's home drive using PowerShell. This script will be executed on a fleet of machines so the path needs to be relative.

Current output:

```
# Create file named 'foo' in home dir
New-Item '~/foo'

# Check if the file exists
[System.IO.File]::Exists('~/foo')
# Returns false
```

Listing the file shows it definitely exists:

```
ls '~/foo'

Directory: C:\Users\tom_n


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----           20/02/2018 14:13              0 foo
```

Am I missing something obvious here? I also tested this with a file that has an actual size, also to no avail.

I'm appreciating any input

Comment: try it with Test-Path (example: Test-Path ~\foo.txt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

Don't use `~` - **use `$HOME`** to refer to the current user's home directory, typically inside `"..."`:

```
[System.IO.File]::Exists("$HOME/foo")
```

Or, preferably, use PowerShell's `Test-Path` cmdlet:

```
Test-Path -LiteralPath "$HOME/foo"
```

<sup>Note:

* PowerShell and .NET types accept `/` and `\` *interchangeably* as the path separators; with a view toward potential cross-platform compatibilty, choose `/`.

* Strictly speaking, since `"$HOME/foo"` is passed to `Test-Path` in *argument mode* (command-line style), enclosing in `"..."` isn't necessary in this case (try `Write-Output $HOME/foo`), but enclosing in `"..."` is a good habit to form, because it works in a wider range of scenarios.</sup>

---

**PowerShell's `~` is *not* fully equivalent to `~` on *Unix*** (in POSIX-like shells) and may not work the way you expect it to in PowerShell:

As explained [in this TechNet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16592.powershell-gotchas.aspx#G1_Tilde)<sup>[1]</sup>, **`~` in PowerShell refers to the home location *as defined by the current location's drive provider*,** which:

- may or may not be the *filesystem*.
- may or may not be *defined*.

On Windows, consider the following example, which uses the registry drive provider:

```
Set-location HKCU:\Software
Set-Location ~
```

which yields the following *error*:

```
Set-Location : Home location for this provider is not set. To set the home location, call "(get-psprovider 'Registry').Home = 'path'".
...
```

As you can see, because the current location was on a drive of the *registry* provider, `~` was interpreted as *that provider's idea of the home location*, which, however, *happens not to be defined*.

An additional crucial difference:

- **On Unix, `~` is a *shell* feature: it must be used *unquoted*, in which case it is expanded to the full, literal home-directory *by the shell***, *before* the target command sees the path, so that the target command sees a *literal* path and *doesn't need to know about `~`*, and, in fact, the standard utilities do *not* know about `~`, which you can verify by contrasting `ls ~` (OK) with `ls '~'` (tries to list a file/dir *literally* named `~`).
- **In PowerShell, `~` is a *PowerShell drive-provider feature***: `~` is passed as-is to drive-provider cmdlets such as `Get-ChildItem` and *they* interpret `~` as referring to the current drive's home location. **External utilities (e.g., `findstr.exe` on Windows) and the .NET Framework do *not* follow this convention** and therefore interpret the `~` as a *literal* filename.

---

By contrast, **[automatic variable `$HOME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) *is* the PowerShell equivalent of Unix `~`**, with added flexibility:

While Unix `~` has to be *unquoted* in order to expand to the user's home directory, PowerShell's automatic `$HOME` variable can be referenced inside *double-quoted* strings as well (as part of normal string expansion (interpolation)).

---

Finally, **.NET types such as `[System.IO.File]` themselves support neither `~` nor `$HOME`**, but by using `"$HOME/..."` it is *PowerShell* that ensures that `$HOME` is replaced with the actual, literal home-directory path before the path string is passed to a .NET method.

---

<sup>[1] [`Get-Help about_Locations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_locations) and [`Get-Help about_Path_Syntax`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_path_syntax), the official help topics on the subject, *should* contain information about `~`,
 but as of this writing *do not.*</sup>

Comment: This should be the god answer.

Answer (score 2):

The PowerShell CmdLet for that is `Test-Path` :

```
Test-Path '~/foo'
```

You can use the Windows file represention with .NET classes

```
[System.IO.File]::Exists('.\foo')
```

Comment: Just be aware that .\Foo may or may not be the same path as ~/Foo. It will only be the same path if your pwd happens to be your home dir.

Comment: Getting a command line that was more *nix-like was one of the original goals for Powershell.

Comment: Good point about `.\foo`, @EBGreen. Note that `~` may refer to a location that is not a _filesystem_ location, as it is relative to the PS drive provider underlying the _current_ location; `$HOME`, by contrast, always refers to user's home directory in the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the `Exists()` does not resolve the home dir specified with `~`. Try using relative or absolute path

Comment: Why the downvote? My statement is correct. You can check with: [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('~/asd') 
That returns 'currentdir/~/asd'. The ~ is not resolved.

Comment: I can only guess but the two things I would change is see if you have find anything authoritative as starting with _I think_ might not be doing you favours. Also your comment actually adds value as a precendent for how those methods work. I would put that into your answer.

Comment: Also, also, if the OP is using ~ in the *nix sense, present working dir is only the right answer if your present working dir happens to be your home dir. It would be wrong in any other dir.